# Firebase: Error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.)

Tags: firebase, next.js

Finally, I (un)successfully deployed my new app. I had many errors on production like, I was used tutorial to implement login/rest/register part and there was an error that `login.js not correctly import signInWithEmailAndPassword from ./firebase`  so I just import it from `import {signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";` as is should. I had another error like `Error [FirebaseError]: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key). on` but I just change my variable to be in quotes `"NEXT(...) "` .
But now I deployment everything and it should work perfect, but when I try to login in I see an alert `Firebase: Error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.).`
and do not know what I suppost to do to fix it.
Not only login form do not work, but also do not work any of other section of application. I can fetch date etc.

btw. i depoleyd  on Vercel.
btw. it all work perfect on local

update.
I updated variable in verbal environmental variable like
`NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID` but there is no difference. In documentation is written that it should be ````NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_MEASUREMENT_ID``` but this approach do not work.

in my env.local:
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_API_KEY=
in my env
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_API_KEY=

(it is in gitignore)

in Vercel server all variable are the same

NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_API_KEY=

Comment: Please provide a minimal code of your application, so people can spot where you have a bug.

Comment: What do you want to know more?

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem with no access to firebase in production I had to do many things:

1. correctly set variables
2. set up authorised domain

ad1
npm i -g vercel
Vercel env add NAME
then connect to variable and select what kind of variable it is (using space).
variable should look like NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_API="..." and used as process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY (without "...").
then Vercel --prod

ad 2 Authentication => settings =>.
Authorized domains and add domain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the loading environment variable into process.env

Installing dotenv package solved my problem.

```
npm install dotenv
```